# A question concerning multilabelled graph(?)

Tags: graph-theory, lo.logic

The question is about how to arrange 2^n girls into groups such that each group consists of at least two girls, and for each group, the girls in it must satisfy the following condtion:
(1) every girl puts her hands on someone else (and only that one)’s shoulders;
We can use graph to represent the relations between girls, points to stand for girls. Whenever a girl puts her hands on another’s shoulders, we draw an arrow from the former to the latter.

For example, the girls are arranged into two groups. In one group, girl a1 puts her hands on a2’s shoulders, a2 and a3 put their hands on each other’s shoulders (and so the two girls have to stand face to face). We will say that there is a 2-circle in such a group. In the other group, there is a 3-circle: girl b3 puts their hands on b4’s shoulders, b4 puts their hands on b5’s shoulder, and b5 puts their hands on b3’s shoulder (sorry for that two of them may have to turn sideways so as to put their hands on the shoulders of the girls standing in front of them). Let call the above arrangement has the (2, 3)-circle.

[image: an example]

To raise the question, we will consider one more condition which is related the colors of the girls’ wearings. We suppose the 2^n girls wear n wearings (either pink or blue). The additional condition (called ‘the n-wearing condition’) is as follows:

a.  Each girl dresses differently from the others (there are 2^n ways of dressing with n items of clothing);

b. For any two girls a and b, if (n-1) of their wearings have the same colors respectively, the two girls whose shoulders a and b put their hands on must have the n-th wearing of the same color.

Question: Is there a (2, 3)-circle arrangement for 8 girls such that the 3-wearing condition is satisfied? If the answer to the above question is negative, we will ask the similar question for 16 girls. Furthermore, for the case of 16 girls, we would like to ask whether there is a (2, 3, 5)-circle arrangement satisfying the 4-wearing condition. How about a (3, 4, 5)-circle arrangement? A (2, 3, 7)-circle arrangement? and so on.

At last, we certainly can ask the similar questions for 2^n girls of n different wearings for any n ≥ 3.
We can only consider those arrangements in each group of which there is a (unque) circle.

Can we characterize fully (that is, with a necessary and sufficient condition), or partially the numbers 2^n for which the above statement hold, if any?

Comment: What is requirement (2)-(ii), and what is a (2,3,5)-circle?

Comment: A (2,3,5)-circle is an arrangement such that there are 3 groups (or more) of 2-circle, 3-circle and 5-circle, respectively.

Comment: Are any two girls a and b with (n-1) of their wearings of the same color allowed to put their hands on a same third girl, instead of two girls? And is one of a and b allowed to put her hands on the other, and the other on a third girl (provided the color conditition on the n-th wearing is satisfied)?

Comment: In other words, we pick an orientation of all the $\binom{n}{2}$ edges of the binary Hamming hypercube graph such that any vertex gets one or more edges going out of it. The vertices are girls, parallel edges all deal with the same wearing, two adjacent vertices are two girls having a different color on only one of their wearings, and a girl $a$ has her hands on the shoulder of the girl $b=f(a)$ whose colors are different for the wearing-edges going out of $a$, and the same for the wearing-edges going in. Then you ask about the set of cycles of the function $f$.

Comment: ... any girl $a$ being identified by the binary color of its $n$ wearings $a=(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)\in\{0,1\}^n$, with, let's say, $1=$ pink and $0=$ blue. Or better, $a\in (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^n$ with $1 \text{ mod } 2=$ pink and $0 \text{ mod }2=$ blue.

Comment: My mistake, not $\binom{n}{2}$ but $n2^{n-1}$ edges.

Comment: @ClaudeChaunier Thanks for commenting. Yes, all the cases you mentioned are allowed.

Comment: According to a computational search, with $n=3$ and the 'wearing condition' the only circles you can obtain are $(2)$, $(3)$, $(4)$, $(5)$, $(2,2)$, and $(2,6)$.

Comment: I found the same six patterns as @CalliopeRyan-Smith for $n=3$ with an exhaustive computational search too. There are a whole lot more for $n=4$ and my search may not finish. But it already found that you can obtain $(2,3,5)$, $(3,4,5)$ and $(2,3,7)$ among 91 patterns found so far.

Answer (score 3):

An exhaustive search of all orientations of the $n2^{n-1}$ hypercube edges for $n=4$ is fast enough once we avoid orientations that are symmetrical to another canonical one. There are exactly $133$ different patterns when counting $(2,2)$ as different from $(2)$. In increasing number of connected components and lexical order of their respective cycle sizes, they are
$$\begin{array}[l] \\
(2), (3), \dots, (14),\\
\hline
(2,2), (2, 3), \dots, (2,12), (2,14),\\
(3,3), (3,4), \dots, (3,11), (3,13),\\
(4,4), (4,5), \dots, (4,10), (4,12),\\
(5,5), (5,6), \dots, (5,9), (5,11),\\
(6,6), (6,7), (6,8), (6,10),\\
(7,7), (8,8),\\
\hline
(2,2,2), (2,2,3), \dots, (2,2,10),\\
(2,3,3), (2,3,4), \dots, (2,3,9),\\
(2,4,4), (2,4,5), \dots, (2,4,8),\\
(2,5,5), (2,5,6),\\
(2,6,6),\\
(3,3,3), (3,3,4), \dots, (3,3,8),\\
(3,4,4), (3,4,5), \dots, (3,4,7),\\
(3,5,5),\\
(4,4,4), (4,4,5), (4,4,6),\\
\hline
(2,2,2,2), (2,2,2,3), \dots, (2,2,2,6), (2,2,2,8),\\
(2,2,3,3), (2,2,3,4), \dots, (2,2,3,6),\\
(2,2,4,4), (2,2,4,5), (2,2,4,8),\\
(2,2,5,5),\\
(2,2,6,6),\\
(2,3,3,3), (2,3,3,4), \dots, (2,3,3,6), (2,3,3,8),\\
(2,4,4,4), (2,4,4,6),\\
(2,4,5,5),\\
(3,3,3,3), (3,3,3,4), (3,3,3,5),\\
(3,3,4,4), (3,3,4,6),\\
(3,3,5,5),\\
(4,4,4,4),\\
\hline
(2,2,2,2,2), (2,2,2,2,3), (2,2,2,2,4),\\
(2,2,2,3,3), (2,2,2,3,4),\\
\hline
(2,2,2,2,2,2),\\
(2,2,2,2,3,3),\\
(2,2,2,2,4,4),\\
(2,2,2,3,3,4),\\
\hline
(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
\end{array}
$$